# how to make a leaflet map using angular along with database?

Tags: angular, dictionary

I have to build a web app using angular which should contain the information of locations with markers and along with a dashboard consists of all other pieces of information.

I used the plugins of leaflet and displayed a map with markers but how to bring the data into markers?

Comment: try this maybe,  [angular markers](https://alligator.io/angular/angular-and-leaflet-marker-service/)

Comment: but I  think you will need something like flask or django to convert your data to geojson and then push to leaflet using api or something like this.

Comment: [flask leaflet](https://belmoussaoui.com/2019/06/28/display-geojson-data-using-flask-and-mongodb/) this uses mongo db but could use postgis,